# System.DirectoryServices.Protocols error '80131500' in classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic, iis-7

I have a `.Net 2.0` class library uses `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;` and working fine while testing against `.Net` console application.

When we call same `dll` from a classic `ASP` application, gives below error.(IIS 7.0).

> Error : ***System.DirectoryServices.Protocols error '80131500'   An
>   operation error occurred.   /login.asp, line 25***

Please help me resolve this.

Thanks & Regards,

Varun

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to use a .net dll in a classic ASP app.  The error code 80131500 is "Cannot create ActiveX component", because System.DirectoryServices.Protocols is not an ActiveX component.
Looks like you could fix this quite easily if "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols" was your project, there's a "Register for COM interop" setting in the build settings for the project that would make it visible to classic ASP.  If you don't have the code for the DirectoryServices object my guess is that the simplest solution would be to create a .Net dll project to wrap the DirectoryServices object and expose the methods you need, build that with "Register for COM interop" then reference your dll in the asp page.

Comment: Will try this, thanks